# Full Httpd bundled with Mod Cluster does not work - libpcre.so.1 error

Tags: httpd.conf, mod-cluster

Playing around with Mod Cluster and following the documentation at http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.3.0/html_single/#Quick_Start_Guide

Following section 2.6 I started my httpd
/opt/jboss/httpd/sbin/apachectl start

The httpd was from the FULL Httpd, Mod Cluster, SSL bundle they have up for download.

Got the error:
error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Comment: How did you resolve the same

Answer (score 0):

Disabling SELinux - Setenforce 0
allows the mod cluster to use the lib